# Android, how to render two (close) controls - a single selection (spinner) and a multiple one (ListView) - visually similar?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, spinner

I need to implement - for my Android app - two user controls quite similar, and very close each other in the UI layout: a single selection control, and a multiple one.
I know the Android solution is to use a Spinner (for single selection) and a ListView (for multiple selection).
I ask: is there a way to let them look more visually similar? By default, a Spinner has a down-arrow symbol on the right, which a ListView has not. **And**, the Spinner is dismissed on an item selection, while the ListView must be closed with the `[back]` button on the phone.
I just don't want to confuse my user: I feel (and suppose users, too) that the attribute "single/multiple" selection doesn't account for such a different UI and usage...

Comment: Have you considered extending the ListView class and adding checkboxes to each row in the list? Then, for the one where you want single selection, you can just iterate through the list and un-check all the other items any time an item is checked. Essentially like a radio button.

Comment: You mean, a custom checkbox *over* the ListView's own?

Comment: If ListView already has it's own, as long as you can manipulate it's checked state, that should work just as well.

Comment: Yes, ListView already has it's own checkboxes... :-) You are right, I could use a ListView for both a Spinner and a ListView... The fact is that a multiselection must be dismissed with the back button on the phone, which I feel quite un-intuitive... I would better use a Spinner for both, but I don't know how to dismiss a multi-selection Spinner: a button on the title?

Comment: At this point I would say the best option is just to stick with the Android convention of using a Spinner and a ListView separately. I don't think many users would find this confusing or unintuitive. If you are still convinced that it is not the right way to handle things, it would be easiest just to write a new activity that can elegantly display either a multiple or single selection screen. With your own activity, you can choose to add buttons or other items wherever you want.

Comment: I think I will go with a Spinner and a ListView separately, for the moment... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do accept Raggedtoad solution: I will stick with the Android convention of using a Spinner and a ListView separately, though I find this solution quite sub-elegant... :-)